# Utilizar Strings em uma estrutura personalizada em C (typedef struct)

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Olá! estou tentando armazenar strings em uma estrutura de dados personalizada (typedef struct), estou utilizando uma biblioteca para trabalhar com strings em C, porem os dados não estão sendo armazenados.

Obrigado a todos pela atenção!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


// Cria uma Estrutura de Dado personalizada
typedef struct
{
    string nome;
    string numero;
} pessoa;



int main(void)
{


    int quantidade = 0;

// Obtem Quantidade de Pessoas
    do
    {
       printf("Quantidade de Pessoas: ");
       scanf("%i", &quantidade);
    }
    while(quantidade < 1);


// Usa Dado personalizados para criar arrays e inserir conteudos

    pessoa contato[quantidade];
    string pesquisa[1];




// Obtem os dados
printf("\n Insira os Dados v \n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++)
    {
        printf("[%i] Nome: ", i);
        scanf("%s", contato[i].nome);

        printf("[%s] Numero: \n \n", contato[i].nome);
        scanf("%s", contato[i].numero);
    }



pesquisa[0] = get_string("Procurar: ");


    for(int b = 0; b < quantidade; b++)
        {
            if (strcmp(contato[b].nome, pesquisa[0]) == 0)   // stir compare (Compara Strings, deve ser V/F)
            {
                printf("\n Encontrado: %s \n\n", contato[b].numero);
                return 0;
        }

        printf("\n Não Encontrado \n\n");
        return 1;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em C não há um tipo específico para String como em outras linguagens como JavaScript, Java e entre outras. Em C, as String são tratadas como array de Caracteres. Então, o código do registro 'pessoa' ficaria assim:

```
typedef struct {//Criando tipo pessoa
    char nome[50];//O tamanho varia com a aplicação do algoritmo.
    char numero[10];
    int idade;
}Pessoa;
```

A linguagem C possui uma biblioteca padrão que é a <string.h> você pode se utilizar de uma função chamada "gets" que serve para ler "strings" no teclado(Muitos afirmam que se trata de uma função insegura, mas no seu caso vai te ajudar bem, recomendo sempre antes limpar o Buffer do Teclado).Assim, o escopo principal ficaria assim:

```
int main(){
    int quantidade=5, i;
    Pessoa pessoa[quantidade];
    for(i=1; i<=quantidade;i++){
        fflush(stdin);//Limpando o Buffer de entrada do Teclado.
        printf("Informe o nome da %d pessoa: ", i);
        gets(pessoa->nome);//Apontando para o Tipo Pessoa e o Campo Nome.
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

No link abaixo tem um exemplo de um problema prático usando Registros e Leitura de Strings.
https://replit.com/join/xtmsyjjknt-riquelmeolivei2

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Nathan , esse código nem compila por que , você está misturando C com C++ , e são linguagens diferentes .  as string's na linguagem C são formadas por vetor de caracteres , assim :

```
/// #include <string.h> /// nAo Adiciona Strings no C, serve apenas para 
                        /// usar as funções da biblioteca string.h
/// Cria uma Estrutura de Dado personalizada
typedef struct
{
    char nome  [28];
    char numero[10];
} pessoa;
```

e esse seu código poderia ser assim :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h> // acessar as fun da bibliot
/// #include <cs50.h>
// Cria uma Estrutura de Dado personalizada
typedef struct
{
    char nome  [28];
    char numero[10];
} pessoa;
char* get_string( char* );
pessoa listar( pessoa ct[], int qtd);
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    int quantidade = 0;
    /// Obtem Quantidade de Pessoas
    do
    {
        printf("Quantidade de Pessoas: ");
        scanf("%i", &quantidade);
    }
    while(quantidade < 1);
    /// Usa Dado personalizados para criar arrays e inserir conteudos
    pessoa contato[quantidade];
    char* pesquisa = "";
    /// Obtem os dados (Tambem não Funcionou)
    for(int a = 0; a < quantidade; a++)
    {
        strcpy( contato[a].nome   , get_string("Nome ---: ") );
        strcpy( contato[a].numero , get_string("Numero -: ") );
    }
    // Procura os dados
    printf("Pesquisar Por < ");
    /// scanf("%s", pesquisa);
    pesquisa = get_string("Nome > ");
    listar( contato,      quantidade );
    for(int b = 0; b < quantidade; b++)
    {
        if ( strcmp(contato[b].nome, pesquisa ) == 0)
        {
            printf("\n Encontrado: %s \n\n", contato[b].nome);
            return 0;
        }
        printf("\n Não Encontrado \n\n");
    }
    return 1;
}
char* get_string( char* st )
{
    char* str = malloc(28);
    printf("%s ", st);
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(str, 27, stdin );
    str[strlen(str) - 1] = 0;
    return str;
}
pessoa listar(pessoa ct[] , int qtd)
{
    for(int j=0; j<qtd; j++)
    {
        printf("Nome ---: %s\n"
               "Número -: %s\n"
        ,ct[j].nome,ct[j].numero);
    }
}
```